# DataBinding an ItemsSource inside an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I still see my self as a beginner developer when it comes to wpf.  I would like to know 2 things

1. where I went wrong or
2. how can I troubleshoot to find the solution.

Situation: [DATA part] I Have:
  DataModel object.  DataFilter object which is basically collection of DataModels + added functions. and DataFiltersGroup, which is used in DataViewModel and has collection of DataFilters I have a DataViewModel object which is basically an observable collection of items. I want to display each DataFilter in an Itemscontrol.

[Current solution] I have build a specialcombo control which derives from combobox [basically a button +combobox].  The specialcombo works fine when deliberately bound.  So I am fairly confident the problem is not with special combo.  When I set ItemsControl.ItemsSource property to the collection of DataFilters and make a DataTemplate of SpecialCombo, the combobox does not show any result (Special combo will not show toggle button if there are no Items - only button will show).  An alternative - approach (2) to binding below let me see the dropdown togglebutton, but dropdown is empty however I know it shouldn't be.

here is sumarized extracts of code

```
public class DataModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //The Item!!
    public int Index {//Normal get set property}
    public string Name {//Normal get set property}
    public int Parent {//Normal get set property}
    public string FullName {//Normal get set property}
    public string DisplayName {//Normal get set property}
    public bool Static {//Normal get set property}
}

public class DataFilters : DataCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> CombinedData;
    public int FilterIndex{//Property... The index of the current item like Index for DataModel.}
    public string ParentName {//property ButtonContent item}
    public int SelectedItem {//Property}
}

//Used as part of DataVieModel.  Also responsible of building each DataFilters item and some other functions
public class DataFilterGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataFilters> FullCollection;
}
```

The WPF object

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PART_ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code behind for WPF on load

```
//DVM = DataVieModel with some other objects.  Filters = DataFilterGroup
PART_ListBox.ItemsSource = DVM.Filters.FullCollection;
PART_ListBox.ItemTemplate = DataFilterTemplate;

//And DataTemplate (1) - shows no combobox
private static DataTemplate DataFilterTemplate
{
    get
    {
        DataTemplate DFT = new DataTemplate();
        DFT.DataType = typeof(DataFilters);

        FrameworkElementFactory Stack = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(VirtualizingStackPanel));
        Stack.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

        FrameworkElementFactory Item = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(SpecialCombo));
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ButtonContentProperty, new Binding("ParentName"));
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ItemsSourceProperty, "CombinedData");
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "DisplayName");
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Index");
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.SelectedValueProperty, "SelectedItem");
        //Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ToggleVisibleProperty, new Binding("ComboVisibility"));
        //Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding("SelectedItem"));

        Stack.AppendChild(Item);

        DFT.VisualTree = Stack;

        return DFT;
    }
}    

//And DataTemplate (2) - shows combobox with no items in dropdown
private static DataTemplate DataFilterTemplate
{
    get
    {
        DataTemplate DFT = new DataTemplate();
        DFT.DataType = typeof(DataFilters);

        FrameworkElementFactory Stack = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(VirtualizingStackPanel));
        Stack.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

        FrameworkElementFactory Item = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(SpecialCombo));
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ButtonContentProperty, new Binding("ParentName"));
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("CombinedData"));
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "DisplayName");
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Index");
        Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.SelectedValueProperty, "SelectedItem");
        //Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ToggleVisibleProperty, new Binding("ComboVisibility"));
        //Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding("SelectedItem"));

        Stack.AppendChild(Item);

        DFT.VisualTree = Stack;

        return DFT;
    }
}
```

Comment: I seriously did not think this question was that complicated, but seems no one can answer it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to punker 76 in another post where I restructured the question (here -> [Can one bind a combobox Itemssource from a datatemplate of a ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555458/can-one-bind-a-combobox-itemssource-from-a-datatemplate-of-a-itemscontrol)) slightly the following had to be done.

DataFilters should become a dependencyobject therefore

```
public class DataFilters : DataCollection
// should become
public class DataFilters : DependencyObject
```

Observalbe collection should also change.  so

```
public ObservableCollection<DataModel> CombinedData;
// should become
public static readonly DependencyProperty CombinedData= DependencyProperty.Register("CombinedData", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataModel>), typeof(DataFilters), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

//and should become a property
public ObservableCollection<DataModel> CombinedData
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<DataModel>)GetValue(CombinedDataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CombinedDataProperty, value); }
}
```

Then in the DataTemplate file the following should change
    Item.SetValue(SpecialCombo.ItemsSourceProperty, "CombinedData");
    //Should change to
    Item.SetBinding(SpecialCombo.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("CombinedData") );

I haven't gone through the entire code above, but I think all the above changes should all be needed in order to bind a combobox type item in a DataTemplate.