# Can one bind a combobox Itemssource from a datatemplate of a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, observablecollection, itemscontrol

Given `ComboBox` in the `ItemsControl` will have different items which is based on the `DataContext` of the item (not of the `ItemsControl`). Can it be done? And how? Preferably from code behind.

I have the following `DataModel`:

```
class Tester
{
    public Tester(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Surname;
    }
}

class TheT
{
    public ObservableCollection<Tester> TesterObject;

    public TheT()
    {
        TesterObject = new ObservableCollection<Tester>();
    }

    public string myDisplayName { get { return "test"; } }

    public void Add(Collection<Tester> col)
    {
        TesterObject.Clear();
        foreach (Tester t in col) { TesterObject.Add(t); }
    }
}
```

In `Window` code I have:

```
ObservableCollection<TheT> myDataV ;
Public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<Tester> Tester1 = new ObservableCollection<Tester>();
    Tester1.Add(new Tester("Sunny", "Jenkins"));
    Tester1.Add(new Tester("Pieter", "Pan"));

    ObservableCollection<Tester> Tester2 = new ObservableCollection<Tester>();
    Tester2.Add(new Tester("Jack", "Sanders"));
    Tester2.Add(new Tester("Bill", "Trump"));

    myDataV = new ObservableCollection<TheT>();
    myDataV.Add(new TheT(Tester1));
    myDataV.Add(new TheT(Tester2));

    IControl.ItemsSource = myDataV;
    IControl.ItemTemplate = TestingDT;
}
```

`IControl` being an `ItemsControl` set up in `XAML`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IControl" Margin="53,375,81,63">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And `DataTemplate` that I have tried all kinds of ways.  But still do not get items to show like below:

```
// the DataTemplate
private DataTemplate TestingDT
{
    get
    {
        DataTemplate DFT = new DataTemplate();
        DFT.DataType = typeof(TheT);

        FrameworkElementFactory Item = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));

        Binding B = new Binding("TesterObject")
        {
            Source = this
        };

        Item.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, B);
        //Item.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "Name");

        DFT.VisualTree = Item;
        return DFT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to explain this a little better with a few code samples.

Comment: I have added code above again.  But previous posts where code was added was ignored, which makes me believe that this might not be possible.  Or people do not like reading through all the code.  Hence my question of whether it is at all possible.  I have posted similar question on codeproject and Microsoft forum... 0 replies for last 2 days.  All examples I find basically have "static data" that goes into combobox.  Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: @DaClan. Im unclear what your problem is. You want to bind the itemsControl to what property? Consider reading overview of MVVM pattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx. It may make more sense if you refactor to view and viewmodel

Comment: I will have a look thanks.  But I want to bind a Combobox Items source to the Datacontext of Each item in an items control.  if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this little changes you should get your expected result

```
public class Tester {
  public Tester(string name, string surname) {
    Name = name;
    Surname = surname;
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Surname { get; set; }

  public override string ToString() {
    return Name + " " + Surname;
  }
}

public class TheT : DependencyObject {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TesterObjectProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TesterObject", typeof(ObservableCollection<Tester>), typeof(TheT),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

  public ObservableCollection<Tester> TesterObject {
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Tester>)GetValue(TesterObjectProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TesterObjectProperty, value); }
  }

  public TheT(Collection<Tester> col) {
    TesterObject = new ObservableCollection<Tester>();
    foreach (Tester t in col) { TesterObject.Add(t); }
  }

  public void Add(Collection<Tester> col) {
    TesterObject.Clear();
    foreach (Tester t in col) { TesterObject.Add(t); }
  }
}

public Window1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  ObservableCollection<Tester> Tester1 = new ObservableCollection<Tester>();
  Tester1.Add(new Tester("Sunny", "Jenkins"));
  Tester1.Add(new Tester("Pieter", "Pan"));

  ObservableCollection<Tester> Tester2 = new ObservableCollection<Tester>();
  Tester2.Add(new Tester("Jack", "Sanders"));
  Tester2.Add(new Tester("Bill", "Trump"));

  var myDataV = new ObservableCollection<TheT>();
  myDataV.Add(new TheT(Tester1));
  myDataV.Add(new TheT(Tester2));

  IControl.ItemsSource = myDataV;
}
```

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverflow.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stackoverflow"
        Title="stackoverflow"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">

  <Grid>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="IControl" Margin="10">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TheT}">
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TesterObject}"
                    MinWidth="80"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

  </Grid>

</Window>
```

hope that helps

Comment: punker... you really is my hero today!!! I have been struggling with a solution to this for so long.  I did not know observable collection had to become a dependency property - in fact most my properties in the real code is except observable collection, which I have been taught is an "inotify" type property and therefore don't need to be dependency.  Thank you!!